# Rounding has unexpected results in Java

Tags: java

I was surprised when I run this code:

```
int  x = (int)4.9f;
System.out.println(x);
```

Why is the result 4 and not 5?

Comment: Because it's not rounding.

Comment: Discard the decimal part from 4.9.What do you get?

Comment: @immibis Well, it actually is rounding. It's just not the kind of rounding people are used to (which is rounding halves away from zero).

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're not rounding, but casting a float as integer. Casting simply removes the decimal part. If you want to round, you must use

```
double x = 4.9f;
System.out.println(Math.round(x));
```

Also, if you want to use explicit upper or lower rounding, you should use `Math.ceil(x)` or `Math.floor(x)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Using a cast simply truncates the value rather than performing proper rounding. You can use [Math.round](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) to get a correctly rounded value, or [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for a choice of 8 different rounding modes.

Answer (score 0):

When `(int)4.9f` is used, it will simply truncate the decimal values (no rounding!). For rounding, you need to use `Math.round()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an int and int cant hold decimal numbers as you are casting a float to int  so it removes the digit after the decimal..

```
int  x = (int)4.9f;
System.out.println(x);
```

So use

```
double x = 4.9f
```